# Junk arrow in mat-select in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

Does anybody know how to get rid of such junk arrow on top left (I guess it's an arrow...)?

[image]

It's in mat-select, it's only visible in Opera in higher res (i.e. 1920x1080; when it comes to 1280x721 I don't see it and that's fine). When some option is checked, it's disappearing for a moment and then it's appearing again.

Here is my code:

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="keywordsForFilter"
class="filter-select form-control col-md-5 margin-b-5px" multiple
(ngModelChange)="filterByKeywords()">
<mat-option *ngFor="let keyword of keywords" [value]="keyword.key">
  {{keyword.value}}
</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: I think it in you content not in select the content on which mat-select in opened

Comment: I guess its because of your css.I tried your code using opera with all resolutions and couldn't see that arrow.Could you share your CSS? Here you can check how I tested your code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pwzzij?file=src/app/select-overview-example.html